# groupBy/reduce an array based on sequence of the element and category

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an array of strings with below structure:

```
A 10
A 20
B 30
B 40
A 30
and so on...
```

I want to compute the average based on the type (A or B) and their sequences, so it will be like this:

```
A 15
B 35
A 30
and so on...
```

Is there any way of using `reduce` or something similar to achieve the array above?

Currently, I can only think of using a loop to manually iterate through all the elements and manually average them based on the type and sequence of the data.

Comment: Please share the data which you have.

Comment: what is your currenct approach?

Comment: @HassanImam The data is included in the post.

Comment: @Bla... Do you have array or object? In case of object, the key with same value will get overridden by the latest value.

Comment: @eramit2010 I can't think of a simple way to achieve the expected result. Currently I'm thinking about using a loop and manually average them based on the type.

Comment: @HassanImam Array of strings as stated in the post..

Comment: @Andreas elegant as in only using the combination of JS functional programming.

Comment: Please update the question with array which you have.

Comment: @HassanImam I already provided the array in the post.

Comment: Your original idea seems solid to me. Loop over the strings, keeping a tally of the current group. Once you find a different group, reset everything.

Comment: Can you write the input in json format? Really not sure what the array looks like.

Comment: who said loops are not elegant? They are to me: easy to understand code, and most of the time more efficient.. if you know how to do it with a loop, no need to loose time trying another method IMHO

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if it's elegant way but you can do reduce and map to get your output.

```js
const input = ["A:10", "A:20", "B:30", "B:40", "A:30"];
const output = input.reduce((acc,v) => {
    // group data based on consecutive keys 
    const [key, value] = v.split(":");
    if(acc.length && acc[acc.length - 1].key === key) { // check if last key and currenct keys are same
        acc[acc.length - 1].value.push(value); // push value to existing value
    } else {
        acc.push({key, value: [value]});
  }
  return acc;
}, []).map(({value, key}) => { // convert grouped array to strings using map
    const average = (value.reduce((a,v) => +a + +v, 0))/value.length; // find average of array of number, [10,20] will result in 15
    return `${key}:${average}`;
})

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd split it into a reduce and map that does different things. First one groups by key and keep account of sum and count, second one transforms it into the response you desire

```js
const arr = ["A 10", "A 20", "B 30", "B 40", "A 30"];
 
var { answer } = arr.reduce((acc, val) => {
  let [type, value] = val.split(" ");
  if (type === acc.seq) {
    let currAnswer = acc.answer[acc.answer.length - 1]
    currAnswer.sum += Number(value);
    currAnswer.count++;
  } else {
    acc.answer.push({type: type, sum: Number(value), count: 1});
    acc.seq = type;
  }
  return acc;
}, {answer: [], seq: ''});

answer = answer.map(val => `${val.type} ${val.sum / val.count}`);
console.log(answer);
```

Edit: I had used two reduces, but second one made no sense. Map makes way more sense

Comment: Thanks.. Seems correct.. Can you please write the code with the code snippet? so that, the it's easier for others to verify..

Answer (score 1):

You could take a closure over the last item and maintain an always correct result by either popping the last result or not and pushing an intermediate string to the result set.

```js
var stringify = ({ key, sum, count }) => [key, sum / count].join(' '),
    array = ['A 10', 'A 20', 'B 30', 'B 40', 'A 30'],
    averages = array
        .reduce((last => (r, s) => {
            var [key, sum] = s.split(' ');
            sum *= 1;
            if (last.key === key) {
                last.sum += sum;
                ++last.count;
            } else {
                last = { key, sum, count: 1, index: r.push(key) - 1 };
            }
            r[last.index] = stringify(last);
            return r;
        })({}), []);

console.log(averages);
```

Comment: What is this `({}), []);` part doing? especially the `({})`, because I guess `[]` is for initialization of the accumulator.

Comment: @Bla..., that is the call of (last => ...)({}) with an (nearly) empty object with a closure over `last`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Why do we need it if it's empty?

Comment: it is used as check with `last.key` without getting a value inside of the callback.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#reduce` and compare the current value and previous value and when they are different take the average of the value and push it in the array.

```js
let arr = ['A 10', 'A 20', 'B 30', 'B 40', 'A 30', 'A 10', 'A 40'],
    sum = 0, length = 0;
    result = arr.reduce((r, s, i, a) => {
      let [key, value] = s.split(/\s+/);
      let [lastKey, lastValue] = (a[i-1] || '').split(/\s+/);
      if(lastKey && key !== lastKey) {
        r.push(`${lastKey} ${sum/length}`);
        sum = +value;
        length = 1;
      } else {
        sum += +value;
        length += 1;
      }
      if(i === a.length - 1) {
        r.push(`${key} ${sum/length}`);
      }
      return r;
    }, []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks. What are the `i` and `a`?

Comment: `i` is index and `a` is the array.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
arr = ["A: 10", "A: 20", "B: 30", "B: 40", "A: 31"];

let outObj = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  let [key, value] = item.split(/[\ :]+/);
  value = parseInt(value);
  if (key in acc) {
    acc[key][0]++;
    acc[key][1] += value;
  } else {
    acc[key] = [1, value];
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

for (key in outObj) {
  console.log(key, ":", outObj[key][1] / outObj[key][0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = ["A:10", "A:20", "B:30", "B:40", "A:30"];

function groupBy(els) {
    let keys = [];
    let values = [];
    input.forEach((el) => {
        const [key, value] = el.split(":");
        if (keys[keys.length - 1] !== key) {
            keys[keys.length] = key;
            values[keys.length - 1] = [parseInt(value)];
        } else {
            values[keys.length - 1].push(parseInt(value))
        }
    });
    return keys.map((el, index) => [el, values[index].reduce((acc, el) => acc + el, 0) / values[index].length])
}
console.log(groupBy(input))
```

Comment: Can you put some explanation about the code inside the forEach? It's a bit confusing, like how you handle duplicate keys.

Comment: if (keys[keys.length - 1] !== key) { <- this line, last key in keys array i compare with current key in foreach